# React rails component render error

Tags: reactjs, components, production, react-rails

I have a Login.js.jsx file with Login component as follows:

> class Login extends React.Component {
>       render() {
>           return (
>             
>               
>           );
>       } }

I am rendering the components as follows in html.haml file

```
= react_component(@component_name , {:params => @params})
```

application.js

> //= require react //= require react_ujs // Our components //= require
>   components/session/login.js //= require_tree ./components/common //=
>   require components //= require_tree .

It works fine in development. But gives following error in production.

> [react-rails] Cannot find component: 'Login' for element ​​
>
> login-1c7ccf0….js:10 Uncaught Error: Cannot find component: 'Login'.
>   Make sure your component is globally available to render.

Comment: Have you tried `@component_name + '.jsx'` ? It may relate to https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/issues/758